# can you automate the creation of declaration of collections in vba

Tags: excel, vba, declaration

I'm playing around trying to learn vba and have chosen to create a Sodoku solver.

I've created something that works for easy and medium puzzles but I've cheated a great deal. I'm actually using the sheets to store possible values for cells 1 to 81. So, on a worksheet I have a grid 81 rows by 9 columns(cells*possibles). I use a count function at the end of the row and VBA checks if its 1 (alone) and it puts that alone value in the grid.

However, what I need now is to to start removing possibles from that row if they are made impossible because of the greater picture.

To the code query: I want to know if I can declare 81 collections to store 9 possible items automatically.
pseudo code:

```
for i = 1 to 81 
    dim coll(i) as int 
next i
```

Or

```
dim my obj-coll as object 
' ....  
dim my obj-coll as collection.
```

Comment: Statements are statements and declarations are declarations. You cannot mix them. On the other hand, I don't see why you wouldn't declare an array of 81 collections: `Dim ObjColl(1 To 81) As Collection`. Note that initially all `ObjColl(i)` will be set to `Nothing` and you need to set them to `New Collection` when convenient; you may of course say `Dim ObjColl(1 To 81) As New Collection` and the array elements will be initialized for you.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, i will look into it.